# Physics-related Differential Equation - Why do beams break?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

I do have a physics-related differential equation question which I need help on.

Given the beam deflection equation:
$$F(x) = EI \frac{d^4u}{dx^4}$$
where $E$ is the Young's Modulus, $I$ is the moment of inertia.

I found that $u(x)$ implies the displacement, $u'(x)$ implies change in displacement, $u''(x)$ implies the bending moment and $u'''(x)$ is the sheer force of the beam.

And relating this formula to a 'breaking a spaghetti' situation- where a spaghetti eventually breaks when we bend it at both ends. Why does that happen? Does the spaghetti break into two because of the maximum bending moment of the spaghetti is exceeded? or the sheer force is exceeded? Or is there any other reasons? How do I explain this situation in terms of the model given?

I've never studied physics before and I apologize if any of the terms here are inaccurate. Please do help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: are you sure about this model being able to describe breaking?

Comment: There are lots of material and environment dependent models. Generally there distinction between static loading and dynamic (repeated).Dynamic loading can lead to fatigue type failures far below the normal static breaking strength of a material (applicable to aluminium for example). Static breaking strength models are generally linear, but actual stresses and strains near the static loading failure of most materials are non-linear. A mathematically interesting model is the maximum distortion energy theory as that can be simplified in a variety ways to allow hypothesis testing.